# How to access to htaccess values (user and pass)?

Tags: php, .htaccess

How can I access to value entered by user with a htaccess pop-up?
Thanks.

Comment: .htaccess has to be configured to know where the passwords are kept, so it's there. You won't be able to access the passwords though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try this?

```
$_SERVER['REMOTE_USER'];
```

or

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_AUTH_USER'];
```

With this you should get the username.

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks a lot man! How can I get the password?

Comment: With $_SERVER['HTTP_AUTH_PASSWORD'];